# How to run php script even in maintenance mode (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I would like to run an external php script (with `wp-load.php`) even if the site is in maintenance mode.

I'm using a plugin to put my website in maintenance (Coming soon)

My script starts with :

`include( '/path/wp-load.php' );`

Is it possible ?

Comment: Did you try doing it?

Comment: Hi @HowardE, I already write my php file. When the cron is running, it return the maintenance page and don't run the script file

Comment: If you're using a maintenance mode plugin to block public Access then it would make sense that no public output would be enabled. Maybe try a different maintenance mode plugin?

Comment: Yeah it makes sense, but I'm searching a way to exclude file to keep running my crontab.. All plugins seems to works the same way, so maybe there's a way to manage this with hooks or something like this..

Comment: You're using a real Cron. The script should run. have you tried triggering a non-public response like maybe using PHP mail

Comment: When I run the script from command line, It shows me the maintenance page. It's because I include `wp-load.php` in the script (I need it). The script is basic, I just need to retrieve some data from wordpress, the reason I include wp-load.

Comment: I understand what you're saying make sure that at the end of the script it uses die() and try returning output via email. See if you get an email?

Comment: The problem is that after the "include" , NOTHING will works cause the maintenance stops the script BEFORE anything.. So even if I put a basic mail after, the script doesn't continue

Comment: Yeah. I'd say to try a different maintenance mode plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It`s been awhile since the moment of the question, but maybe a solution will help someone in the future.

Just define IS_WP_CLI variable in the beginning of your script .

```
...
define('IS_WP_CLI', true); // Avoid maintenance mode
require_once HOME_PATH . '/wp-load.php';
...
```

If IS_WP_CLI defined -> maintenance mode will not be instantiated.

```
if (defined('IS_WP_CLI')) { return ; }
```

Now you can run cli scripts even if maintenance mode is active.